# Find Pattern of Bytes in Byte Array

Tags: c++, search, byte

today I am trying to find a pattern of bytes in an array (in this case pointer)

I do know I could use std::string needle() and haystack etc. but I was wondering if I could use that with BYTE (unsigned char)?

I also know the length of the BYTE *_zone so that's not an issue either. Any ways I could go forth to do this? (also any code examples are appreciated :))

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find()` method of `std::string` is a member function that is intended to find another `std::string` or a character array `char*` inside the std::string

So to answer your question if the haystack is a `std::string` you should be able to pass the `char*` arrays directly to the find methods.

If the haystack is not a `std::string` you can make a `std::string` out of it and then do the same.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is actually a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. You can use `std::basic_string<BYTE>` instead, and most (all?) `std::string` functionality, in particular `.find()`, will just work.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use existing library functions, implement your favorite generic string matching algorithm, for example [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) or [Rabin-Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm).